# BroadcastReceiver is not working

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I am using BroadcastReceiver in android app to get OTP message automatically.But BroadcastReceiver is not working and don't find the bug so please help me.I put **Log.d("onReciver","on")** in **onReceive()** to check but its not working.

**IncomingMessage.java**

```
public class IncomingMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("onReciver","on");
        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null)
            {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj .length; i++)
                {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])                                                                                                    pdusObj[i]);
                    String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    String senderNum = phoneNumber ;
                    Log.d("sender NUm",senderNum);
                    String message = currentMessage .getDisplayMessageBody();
                    try
                    {
                        if (senderNum.equals("(727)594-3351"))
                        {
                            OtpVarificationActivity Sms = new OtpVarificationActivity();
                            Sms.recivedSms(message );
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("BR error",e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("BR error1",e.toString());

        }

    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
...
...
...
<receiver android:name="com.appsprotocol.dcntv.broadcast.IncomingMessage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: How are you triggering the receiver?

Comment: creating object of Incoming message class

Comment: did your code triggered when message received?

Comment: yupp but i think <receiver> triggered broadcastReceiver

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example

**Register Receiver in AndoridMenifest.xml :**

```
            <receiver android:name="com.example.tosc185.readincommingsmsdemo.SmsListener">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

**Receiver Class :**

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null) {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        }
                        else {
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i], String.format(Locale.US, null));
                        }
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "From -" + msg_from + " : Body- " + msgBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (msg_from.equalsIgnoreCase("5555")) {
                            MainActivity.insertCode(msgBody);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
//                            Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okk but my query is my BroadcastReceiver is not calling when i run app.If its calling then i can see log message which i put in onReceive()

Answer (score 0):

Try adding priority to your receiver in manifest. This worked for me.

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: not working and what is android:priority please tell me?

Comment: see this link for information about priority https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Add enabled and exported in manifest file. Below you can find the code sample for manifest.

```
<receiver
            android:name=".SmsReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: @RahulDev:: are you using marshmellow? and make sure you have implemented the [BRAODCAST_SMS] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BROADCAST_SMS) permission.

Comment: yes i am using it and try to use BROADCAST_SMS permission but it through me error  "permission is only granted to the system apps".whats the mean of this error?

Comment: I got it but its not problem of BROADCAST_SMS permission.Its because API 23 did't accept permission automatically.I set it going to mobile app permissions and its working. thanks for guiding me